# How to append to a list two numbers from within the list that add up to a number in the list?

Tags: python

First, I want to find the highest number in the list which is the second number in the list, then split it in two parts. The first part contains the 2nd highest number, while the second part contains the number from the list that sums to the highest number. Then, return the list

eg: input: [4,9,6,3,2], expected output:[4,6,3,6,3,2] 6+3 sums to 9 which is the highest number in the list

Please code it without itertools.

python

```
def length(s):
    val=max(s)
    s.remove(val)
    for j in s:
        if j + j == val:
            s.append(j)
            s.append(j)
        return s
```

Here's what I have but it doesn't return what the description states.

Any help would be appreciated as I spent DAYS on this.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you limited to sub-lists of length = 2? Because `4 + 3 + 2 = 9`

Comment: only two numbers !

Answer (score 1):

The main issue in your code seems to be that you are editing the list `s` whilst iterating through it, which can cause issues with the compiler and is generally just something you want to avoid doing in programming. A solution to this could be iterating through a copy of the original list.

The second problem is that your program doesn't actually find the second biggest value in the list, just a value which doubles to give you the biggest value.

The final problem (which I unfortunately only noticed after uploading what I thought was a solution) is that the split values are appended to the end of the list rather than to the position where originally the largest value was.

Hopefully this helps:

```
def length(array):
    val = max(array)
    idx = array.index(val) # gets the position of the highest value in the array (val)
    array.remove(val)
    for i in array.copy(): # creates a copy of the original list which we can iterate through without causing buggy behaviour
        if max(array) + i == val:
            array = array[:idx] + [max(array), i] + array[idx:]
# Redefines the list by placing inside of it: all values in the list upto the previous highest values, the 2 values we got from splitting the highest value, and all values which previously went after the highest value.
            return array
```

This will return `None` if there is no value which can be added to the second highest value to get the highest value in the given array.

**Input**:

```
print(length([1,2,3,4,5]))
print(length([4,8,4,3,2]))
print(length([11,17,3,2,20]))
print(length([11,17,3,2,21]))
```

**Output**:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1]
[4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2]
[11, 17, 3, 2, 17, 3]
None
```

Here are [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#slicings) on list slicing (which are impossible to understand) and a [handy tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-slicing/).

Comment: I faced the same problem how would you append it in the right section of the list ?

Comment: Just found out that you can also use `list.insert(index, object)`, which is easier to read but slightly worse in performance and usability. Added in the comments now.

Comment: It only returns [4]

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally changed the indentation when adding in comments which lead to the code breaking down. Fixed that now

Answer (score 0):

Since you are limited to 2 numbers, a simple nested loop works.

```
def length(s):
    val = max(s)
    idx = s.index(val)
    s.remove(val)
    for i in range(len(s) - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(s)):
            if s[i] + s[j] == val:
                s = s[:idx] + [s[i], s[j]] + s[idx:]
                return s

print(length([4,9,6,3,2]))
```

Output:

```
[4, 6, 3, 6, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

when you say "The first part contains the 2nd highest number" does that mean second highest number from the list or the larger of the two numbers that add up the largest number from list?

Here I assume you just wanted the larger of the two numbers that add up to the largest number to come first.

```
def length(s:list):
#start by finding the largest value and it's position in the list:
largest_pos = 0
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] > s[largest_pos]:
        largest_pos = i
# find two numbers that add up to the largest number in the s
for trail in range(len(s)):
    for lead in range(trail, len(s)):
        if (s[trail] + s[lead]) == s[largest_pos]:
            if s[trail] > s[lead]:
                s[largest_pos] = s[trail]
                s.insert(largest_pos +1, s[lead])
            else:
                s[largest_pos] = s[lead]
                s.insert(largest_pos + 1, s[trail])
            return s
# if no two numbers add up to the largest number. return s
return s
```

Answer (score 0):

I used deque library
first to find the highest element or elements then remove all of them and replace them with second high value and rest like : 9 replace with 6 and 3 in example:

```
from collections import deque

l = [4, 9, 6, 3, 2]
a = deque(l)
e = a.copy()

s = max(a)
while s in a:
    a.remove(s)       # remove all highest elements

s2 = max(a)           # find second high value

c = s - s2

for i in l:
    if i == s:
        w = e.index(i)  # find index of high values
        
        e.remove(max(e))
        e.insert(w, s2)
        e.insert(w+1, c)

print(list(e))
```